# how to create a record in workbench using REST Explorer

Tags: rest-api, post

I am trying to create a new account record using post method in work bench. But I am unable to follow exact format of map url and it is giving the following error. Please suggest me a correct way how to do it or do I need any extra procedure to follow. Please suggest me.  [image]

Comment: have you created a custom rest service class?  when we create custom rest service then we use /services/apexrest/urlmapping

Comment: No @Ratan. I didn't create any rest service class.

Comment: cool then you need to use like Mr.Frodo mentioned in answer to create account record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to perform it this way

[image]

**Note:** You should try to grab the URL by GET method first.Then apply post on that URL.

Comment: please give an example for GET method, how to grab it? @Mr.Frodo

Comment: I would suggest you to try with the URL which i have applied first in POST method.