# Unable to get ApexPageMember ID Tooling API

Tags: tooling-api

I'm new to Tooling API and I'm trying to update an existing Visualforce page from a class through Tooling API by Tooling API ApexPageMember object. 
However, I am unable to create the ApexPageMember object. I am using the below method in ToolingNewPage class.

```
private static String baseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() 
    + '/services/data/v28.0/tooling/';                                                                       public static void createApexPageMember(String mid,String axid, String classBody) {
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();


    req.setEndpoint(baseUrl + 'sobjects/ApexPageMember');

req.setMethod('POST');

req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setBody('{"MetadataContainerId" : "'+mid+'", "ContentEntityId" : "'+axid+'", "Body": "'+classbody+'"}');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

System.debug('++++++++++++++++++'+res);
}
```

However, on running in developer console, I keep getting the

> error Status=Bad Request StatusCode=400

I am running using the following code:

```
ToolingNewPage.createApexPageMember('402900000006uLQAAY','06690000005eAf5','boon');
```

where first is MetadataContainerID, then PageID, then Updated Body.
What am I doing wrong?

And after the ApexPageMemberis created, do I need to create ContainerAsyncRequest method to update the Visualforce page? How can I create and how to call this?  Please help me and provide me the relevant code to go forward.

Comment: Looks like your URL is not correct, try with hardcoding!

Comment: Usually I test Apex webservices using [workbench](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122495/how-to-create-a-record-in-workbench-using-rest-explorer)

Comment: I found out that it is necessary to have a createContainerAsyncRequest method and call it with the MetadataContainerID to finally update the page.